# How can I write this more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, scope, performance

Whether or not this is the best way to do this, I don't care - but in this case I have 2 identical search bars which I toggle based on screen width. One shows for mobile, one shows for desktop. The code below works well but there's so much repetition, there must be a better way to write it.

The HTML:

```
<div class="search-wrp">
    <input type="text" class="search" data-which="mobile" value="Search" />
    <input type="button" value="&nbsp;" class="go sprite" data-which="mobile" />
</div>

<div class="search-wrp">
    <input type="text" class="search" data-which="desktop" value="Search" />
    <input type="button" value="&nbsp;" class="go sprite" data-which="desktop" />
</div>
```

The JS:

```
 $('.search').focus(function () {
    var viewport = $(this).attr('data-which');
    if ($('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]').val().toLowerCase() == "search") {     $('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]').val(""); }
}).focusout(function () {
    var viewport = $(this).attr('data-which');
    if ($('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]').val() == "") { $('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]').val("Search"); }
}).keypress(function (event) {
    var viewport = $(this).attr('data-which');
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.go[data-which="' + viewport + '"]').click();
    }
});

$('.go').click(function () {
    var viewport = $(this).attr('data-which');
    if ($('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]').val() == null || $('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]').val() == "Search") {
        alert("Please enter a search phrase.");
    } else {
        window.location = "http:" + "//" + window.location.host + "/Search.aspx?phrase=" + $('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]').val();
    }
});
```

I would like to use a variable for '.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]' and I'd also like to be able to define viewport just once in a way that still makes it usable within the functions. However my attempts have all run into scope issues.

Comment: sorry @Ingo, I didn't see this comment at first. 

The .focus function clears the word "Search" from the text input when the user clicks into it. The .focusout function puts "Search" back if the user didn't type anything. The rest is for sending the browser to a search page with the search term in the URL while ensuring it doesn't use "Search" or a blank as the search term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than repeatedly call `$('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]')` inside each function, store it in a variable. E.g:

```
$('.search').focus(function () {
    var viewport = $(this).attr('data-which'),
        search = $('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]');
    if (search.val().toLowerCase() == "search") { search.val(""); }
}).focusout(function () {
    var viewport = $(this).attr('data-which'),
        search = $('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]');
    if (search.val() == "") { search.val("Search"); }
}).keypress(function (event) {
    var viewport = $(this).attr('data-which');
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.go[data-which="' + viewport + '"]').click();
    }
});

$('.go').click(function () {
    var viewport = $(this).attr('data-which'),
        search = $('.search[data-which="' + viewport + '"]');
    if (search.val() == null || search.val() == "Search") {
        alert("Please enter a search phrase.");
    } else {
        window.location = "http:" + "//" + window.location.host + "/Search.aspx?phrase=" + search.val();
    }
});
```

Always store the return value of a function if you need that value more than once.

Comment: Thank you! This is a big improvement. Do you know if it's possible to eliminate even more repetition by somehow declaring viewport and search outside of the chain of functions?

Comment: @MaryPelletier Only if there is only one `.search`, but it looks like there is probably more than one.